# Duplicate interface definition when mixing Objective-C files in projects in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a situation where I have one XCode project, and I have another project that shares most of the code with it, with some small differences. So in the project, most of the files are just references to the files from the original project, and anywhere I need to make differences, I copy the file and change the copy. This is useful because for the files that are shared, any changes made in one project will automatically be reflected in the other. This has worked fine for the most part.

Now I am running into a problem where I need to make a change in a header file that is included among a lot of files. Call this file "shared.h". So I do the same thing I did before, delete the reference and copy the file over and change it.

But now the problem is that when I compile, I get hundreds of "duplicate interface declaration" errors from files that include this header. I understand perfectly why, but I just can't think of a way to fix it.

The reason is that suppose you have a file that includes headers from both the original project and the new project. In the files that are references to the original project, when you do `#import "shared.h"`, they will import the file from the directory of the original project; and in the files that are copied into the new project, when you do `#import "shared.h"`, they will import the file from the directory of the new project. So the classes that are defined in the header will be imported twice into the two different files, hence you get a duplicate interface definition. Objective-C's `#import` will include once per file, but since these are two different files, it will still include both of them.

I thought that the header that is actually listed in my project will take precedence over all else (at least I want it to do that), but it appears that putting headers into the project don't actually affect building of code at all. So now I am lost.

The only solution I can think of at this point is to duplicate all the code in the original project and move it over, to completely separate the projects. But that is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I actual think this is more of a problem with project management. I think linking in code from another project like this sounds really fragile. I.e. if project A is the original project and project B links in some of it's code, changes to project A may break project B without project B having any ability to restrict or control the influence of those changes.

I'd consider compiling the first project as a static library or framework and giving it a version number. Then the second project can import the library. Overrides should not be handled by effectively manipulating the class path. I've seen that done in Java and it's always an absolute last resort to work around bad code. Instead you should be making use of Objective C's abilities - inheritance, categories, etc to add or extend the functionality.

If you have versioned the first project (i.e. /v0.0.1/headers) then project B can keep using v0.0.1 of A until you are read to upgrade to v0.0.2. Then you can re-import A's static library, update a build path or whatever to point B at the new version you want to code against.

In summary, I would not recommend your technique of project management at all and suggest strongly that you rethink it.

Comment: Yes, a utilities framework you can share amongst all your projects is definitely the way to go. Even so, I ran into the "duplicate interface declaration" today and it took me ages to find it. Problem? I had already incorporated the category into my utilities framework, but forgot to remove it from the project in which I had first developed it.

Comment: By the way, user102008, it would be nice to either accept Derek's answer or ask for more help if you're not sure how to implement a framework or static library. Don't leave us this way!